# Windows Store 10 App Dev: Total file system access

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm thinking of porting a desktop file launcher app to the Windows 10 store app.
So being a program launcher it would need unrestricted access to ANY folder/path/exe on the users system, it's a configurable program/argument launcher. Basically global file system access. Is this possible without the user having to choose anything?

For example the app could call: notepad.exe "f:\data\test.txt"

or: c:\program files\adobo\photoshock\photo.exe "g:\data\test.tiff"

Answer (score 0):

No, UWP apps have limited access to the file system by design.

You may want to try converting you desktop app into a "modern" desktop app thru the [Project Centennial](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2016/B829).